# C99 recursive matrix multiplication. How to acces indices?

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to implement a version of following algorithm:
[image: Algorithm]

But instead of reducing the problem to 1 multiplication I want to reduce the matrices dimensions to 16*16 and multiply these Blocks.

I already have an implementation for a blocksize of 1*1 (same as the algorithm mentioned before). I need to expand my version for bigger blocks(e.g. 16*16).

Multiplying blocks isn't hard. My problem is accessing the indices of my blocks, since I have to use the recursive call of my 1*1-block version:

recursive_mult(n/2 , stride , &A[0+0*stride] , &B[0+0*stride] , &C[0+0*stride]) ;

...where n is the size of the current blocks. And Im using a stride in the matrices for perfomance-testing.

So I only pass on references of my matrices.

Is there a way to work around this, without changing the recursive call to pass on start-indices of blocks?

Comment: You cannot reduce the matrix dimensions to 16×16 without rearranging data in memory (as by copying the 256 elements involved to a temporary buffer that is 16×16). You can pass a pointer to the start of the submatrix that starts at element i, j by passing `&A[i + j*stride]`. The called routine, having received that address in a pointer `p`, would access elements relative to that starting point as `p[x + y*stride]`, using 0 ≤ x < 16, 0 ≤ y < 16, and the same stride as the calling routine. Is that what you want?

Comment: Im using temporary arrays to copy the current blocks. I just recently startet programming in c and Im not that familiar with pointers. So how would I create a pointer?

Comment: If i use something like double* p = &A; I wont be able to access the other elements with p[x...].

Comment: What “other elements”? Given `double *p = &A[i + j*stride];`, `p[x + y*stride]` will access the element `A[(i+x) + (j+y)*stride]`. Thus, given that definition of `p`, `p` can access all the elements in the 16×16 submatrix that starts at i, j.

Comment: In any case, you cannot determine from a pointer anything about the array into which it points, other than the type of its elements.  Information about indices or sizes needs to be conveyed separately.  That may well mean that the signature for your 1x1 case is inadequate for other cases you need to accommodate.